# Accesing items with custom keys in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have object like this:

```
{
"first" : "value1",
"second" : "value2"
}
```

I want to access both values in `for` cycle. Order of getting values doesn't mind. Usage is for something like `value = value + "something"`. How to acces values which key names I don't know? Of course I can get keys from helping array like:

```
var keys = ["first", "second"];
```

And then get them by index and with them get value1 and value2 from my original array. Is there some better way? For some reason foreach doesn't work either.

Comment: The array at the top of the question is not JavaScript syntax.

Comment: You should clarify what you want here. You are showing square brackets `[]`, which means array, but `=>` is not valid within an array and arrays don't have "keys". Objects, on the other hand do have "keys"`.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys, loop over that. You can slso use `Object.values()` to get the values, and `Object.entries()` to get both together.

Comment: Thank you for replies. My solution is understanding the datatype like object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has a for ... in to loop through keys

```
for (var key in object) {
   console.log(object[key])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution seems profesional. Getting keys in for cycle is really interesting functionality of js.

Answer (score 1):

To access *both* values:

```js
const data = {
  "first": "value1",
  "second": "value2"
};

// (1) for-loop

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log("for-loop:", key, value);
}

// (2) Array.prototype.forEach

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log("Array.prototype.forEach:", key, value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the keys and values separately in an array you can do the following:

```
var data = {
"first" : "value1",
"second" : "value2"
}
var keys = Object.keys(data)
var values = Object.values(values)
```

Printing them out individually would give you:

```
console.log(keys)
Output: ["first", "second"]

console.log(values)
Output: ["value1", "value2"]
```